# Script javascript no muestra mensaje con variables

Tags: javascript, java, html

Estoy haciendo un script utilizando javascript básico. Este es el enunciado del problema:

Vamos a realizar un script que nos pregunte el nombre y la edad. Nos
responderá con un saludo y nos dirá si somos menores o mayores de edad y
los días que hemos vivido. La respuesta se muestra en dos filas diferentes, en la primera está
el nombre y en la siguiente el resto.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   var nombre
>   nombre=prompt("¿Cómo te llamas?");
>   var edad
>   edad=prompt("¿Cuántos años tienes?");
>   if (edad && hombre) {
>     var dias= edad * 365;
>     if (edad >=18) {
>       alert("Te llamas "+ nombre + "\n" + "Eres mayor de edad y llevas " + dias + "viviendo");
>       }
>       else {
>       alert("Te llamas "+ nombre + "\n" + "Eres menor de edad y llevas " + dias + "viviendo");
>       }
>     }
>   else {
>     alert("No has introducido la edad o el nombre");
>   }
> </script>
> ```

El problema reside en que me muestra el mensaje arriba en el navegador, el de Cómo te llamas? y el de Cuantos años tienes? Pero no me muestra las alertas, indique lo que indique no aparecen esos mensajes. Si no indico nada aparece correctamente el else: No has introducido la edad o el nombre.
Agradecería si me pudieses ayudar algo, el navegador es chrome. Estoy aprendiendo...

Comment: En `if (edad && hombre)` estás poniendo `hombre` y la variable se llama `nombre`.

Comment: La falta de sueño imagino. Dios que tonto. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por favor revisa la consola cuando corras tu código, nunca lo desarrolles completo a detalle, siempre empieza por lo básico.
Copié y pegué tu código en la consola del DevTool de Google Chrome e indica que la variable "hombre" no existe.

```js
var nombre, edad, dias, txt;
nombre=prompt("¿Cómo te llamas?");
edad=prompt("¿Cuántos años tienes?");
if (edad && nombre) {
  if(edad <= 0)
    alert("Por favor ingresa una edad valida.");
  else {
    dias = edad * 365;
    txt = edad >=18?'mayor':'menor';
    alert("Te llamas "+ nombre + "\n" + "Eres "+txt+" de edad y llevas " + dias + " viviendo.");
  }
}
else
  alert("No has introducido la edad o el nombre");
```

También empieza aplicando las buenas practicas.

1. Declarar todas las variables separadas por comas.
2. Usar operadores ternarios para reducir el espacio del código.
3. Eliminar redundancias como la alerta de respuesta.
4. No aplicar llaves a los condicionales que cuentan con una sola sentencia.
5. Indentar el código.

A largo plazo te darás cuenta de la importancia de aplicar estas y otras practicas.

Comment: LLevas razón, debería de haber revisado la consola, pero creo que en Atom no lo indica, alomejor debería cambiar de editor...